# Question about "The Logic of Provability" by George S. Boolos

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a question about "The Logic of Provability" by George S. Boolos

First line on page 49,$\vdash x<sy\leftrightarrow x<y\lor x=y$

Second line on page 49,
$ \vdash F_y (sy) \leftrightarrow (F∧G) $.I don't understand here.

$F (y)$ should be able to be expressed as

$$ F (y) \equiv \forall x (x <y → G(y)) $$
So the above formula is
$$ \vdash\forall x (x <sy → G_y (sy)) \leftrightarrow \forall x (x <y → G(y)) \land G (y) $$
But it doesn't seem like a valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

By $x<sy ↔ x<y∨x=y$, if we "plug it" into $F(sy) := ∀x(x<sy → G)$ we get:

> $F(sy) \equiv ∀x((x<y ∨ x=y) → G)$.

But $(P \lor Q) \to R$ is equivalent to: $(P \to R) \land (Q \to R)$ and thus we have: $F(sy) \equiv ∀x((x<y \to G) \land (x=y → G))$, from which:

> $F(sy) \equiv ∀x(x<y \to G) \land ∀x(x=y → G)$.